# Select mysql query between 'date1' and 'date2'

Tags: php, mysql, date

good afternoon, I have this code to query an INSERT made before to MySQL with date(); (just name, email, date) but, when I query the info back it returns nothing...

This is the query page:

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registro");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Error al conectar a la BD";
}

$fec1 = isset($_POST['fecha1']) ? $_POST['fecha1'] : NULL;
$fec2 = isset($_POST['fecha2']) ? $_POST['fecha2'] : NULL;
$nom = 'Nombre Completo';
$ema = 'Correo Electronico';
$fec = 'Fecha de Registro';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from registro where date between '$fec1' and '$fec2'");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".$nom."</th>";
echo "<th>".$ema."</th>";
echo "<th>".$fec."</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

And this is the main page, wich inserts data on MySQL:

```
<?php

#error_reporting(0);

$sqlhost = 'localhost';  
$sqluser = 'root';       
$sqlpass = '';           
$sqldb   = 'registro';   
$sqltable= 'registro';

function captcha() {
  $k="";
  $param="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  $max=strlen($param)-1;

  for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) { 
    $k.=$param{mt_rand(0,$max)};
  }
  return $k;
}

$db = mysqli_connect($sqlhost, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqldb); //Nuestra variable para establecer la conexión a la base de datos
if(!$db){die("Error al conectar con la db" . mysql_error());}

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : NULL; // Tomamos el texto del input "nombre"
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL; // Tomamos el texto del input "apellido"
$date = date('Y-m-d');

// Insertaremos la información a la tabla Nombre y Apellido, donde VALUES declara el texto que ingresaremos
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$sqltable."(name, email, date) VALUES('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$date."');";

mysqli_select_db($db,$sqldb); //verificaremos la conexión a nuestra base de datos
$insert_value = mysqli_query($db, $query); // Declaramos la variable $insert_value para usarla cómo un bool, en caso de que esta consulta falle
    if(!$insert_value) //Crearemos la consulta
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db)); // Si falla, nos mostrará este texto, seguido del error.

mysqli_close($db); // Detenemos la conexión de la base de datos

?>
```

The `$fec1` and the `$fec2` variables, comes from php calendar and when I use that, it uses this format:

```
Fecha inicio:  
1/11/2016
 Fecha final:  
7/11/2016
```

I understand that MySQL stores date like this 'YYYY-mm-dd' I took a look to the calendar code but I can't query the results...

This is the calendar code:

```
<?php
function calcula_numero_dia_semana($dia,$mes,$ano){
    $numerodiasemana = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia,$ano));
    if ($numerodiasemana == 0) 
        $numerodiasemana = 6;
    else
        $numerodiasemana--;
    return $numerodiasemana;
}

//funcion que devuelve el último día de un mes y año dados
function ultimoDia($mes,$ano){ 
    $ultimo_dia=28; 
    while (checkdate($mes,$ultimo_dia + 1,$ano)){ 
       $ultimo_dia++; 
    } 
    return $ultimo_dia; 
} 

function dame_nombre_mes($mes){
     switch ($mes){
        case 1:
            $nombre_mes="Enero";
            break;
        case 2:
            $nombre_mes="Febrero";
            break;
        case 3:
            $nombre_mes="Marzo";
            break;
        case 4:
            $nombre_mes="Abril";
            break;
        case 5:
            $nombre_mes="Mayo";
            break;
        case 6:
            $nombre_mes="Junio";
            break;
        case 7:
            $nombre_mes="Julio";
            break;
        case 8:
            $nombre_mes="Agosto";
            break;
        case 9:
            $nombre_mes="Septiembre";
            break;
        case 10:
            $nombre_mes="Octubre";
            break;
        case 11:
            $nombre_mes="Noviembre";
            break;
        case 12:
            $nombre_mes="Diciembre";
            break;
    }
    return $nombre_mes;
}

function dame_estilo($dia_imprimir){
    global $mes,$ano,$dia_solo_hoy,$tiempo_actual;
    //dependiendo si el día es Hoy, Domigo o Cualquier otro, devuelvo un estilo
    if ($dia_solo_hoy == $dia_imprimir && $mes==date("n", $tiempo_actual) && $ano==date("Y", $tiempo_actual)){
        //si es hoy
        $estilo = " class='hoy'";
    }else{
        $fecha=mktime(12,0,0,$mes,$dia_imprimir,$ano);
        if (date("w",$fecha)==0){
            //si es domingo 
            $estilo = " class='domingo'";
        }else{
            //si es cualquier dia
            $estilo = " class='diario'";
        }
    }
    return $estilo;
}

function mostrar_calendario($mes,$ano){
    global $parametros_formulario;
    //tomo el nombre del mes que hay que imprimir
    $nombre_mes = dame_nombre_mes($mes);

    //construyo la tabla general
    echo '<table class="tablacalendario" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" border="0">';
    echo '<tr><td colspan="7" class="tit">';
    //tabla para mostrar el mes el año y los controles para pasar al mes anterior y siguiente
    echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0"><tr><td class="messiguiente">';
    //calculo el mes y ano del mes anterior
    $mes_anterior = $mes - 1;
    $ano_anterior = $ano;
    if ($mes_anterior==0){
        $ano_anterior--;
        $mes_anterior=12;
    }
    echo "<a href='index.php?$parametros_formulario&nuevo_mes=$mes_anterior&nuevo_ano=$ano_anterior'><span>&lt;&lt;</span></a></td>";
    echo "<td class='titmesano'>$nombre_mes $ano</td>";
    echo "<td class='mesanterior'>";
    //calculo el mes y ano del mes siguiente
    $mes_siguiente = $mes + 1;
    $ano_siguiente = $ano;
    if ($mes_siguiente==13){
        $ano_siguiente++;
        $mes_siguiente=1;
    }
    echo "<a href='index.php?$parametros_formulario&nuevo_mes=$mes_siguiente&nuevo_ano=$ano_siguiente'><span>&gt;&gt;</span></a></td></tr></table></td></tr>";
    echo '  <tr>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">L</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">M</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">X</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">J</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">V</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">S</td>
                <td width="14%" class="diasemana">D</td>
            </tr>';

    //Variable para llevar la cuenta del dia actual
    $dia_actual = 1;

    //calculo el numero del dia de la semana del primer dia
    $numero_dia = calcula_numero_dia_semana(1,$mes,$ano);
    //echo "Numero del dia de demana del primer: $numero_dia <br>";

    //calculo el último dia del mes
    $ultimo_dia = ultimoDia($mes,$ano);

    //escribo la primera fila de la semana
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
        if ($i < $numero_dia){
            //si el dia de la semana i es menor que el numero del primer dia de la semana no pongo nada en la celda
            echo '<td class="diainvalido"><span></span></td>';
        } else {
            echo "<td " . dame_estilo($dia_actual) . "><span><a href='javascript:devuelveFecha($dia_actual,$mes,$ano)'>$dia_actual</a></span></td>";
            $dia_actual++;
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    //recorro todos los demás días hasta el final del mes
    $numero_dia = 0;
    while ($dia_actual <= $ultimo_dia){
        //si estamos a principio de la semana escribo el <TR>
        if ($numero_dia == 0)
            echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td " . dame_estilo($dia_actual) . "><span><a href='javascript:devuelveFecha($dia_actual,$mes,$ano)'>$dia_actual</a></span></td>";
        $dia_actual++;
        $numero_dia++;
        //si es el uñtimo de la semana, me pongo al principio de la semana y escribo el </tr>
        if ($numero_dia == 7){
            $numero_dia = 0;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    //compruebo que celdas me faltan por escribir vacias de la última semana del mes
    if ($numero_dia != 0){
        for ($i=$numero_dia;$i<7;$i++){
            echo '<td class="diainvalido"><span></span></td>';
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}   

function formularioCalendario($mes,$ano){
    global $parametros_formulario;
echo '
    <br><form action="index.php?' . $parametros_formulario . '" method="POST">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" class=tform>
    <tr>';
echo '
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        Mes: <br>
        <select name=nuevo_mes>
        <option value="1"';
if ($mes==1)
 echo "selected";
echo'>Enero
        <option value="2" ';
if ($mes==2) 
    echo "selected";
echo'>Febrero
        <option value="3" ';
if ($mes==3) 
    echo "selected";
echo'>Marzo
        <option value="4" ';
if ($mes==4) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Abril
        <option value="5" ';
if ($mes==5) 
        echo "selected";
echo '>Mayo
        <option value="6" ';
if ($mes==6) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Junio
        <option value="7" ';
if ($mes==7) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Julio
        <option value="8" ';
if ($mes==8) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Agosto
        <option value="9" ';
if ($mes==9) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Septiembre
        <option value="10" ';
if ($mes==10) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Octubre
        <option value="11" ';
if ($mes==11) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Noviembre
        <option value="12" ';
if ($mes==12) 
    echo "selected";
echo '>Diciembre
        </select>
        </td>';
echo '      
        <td align="center" valign="top">
        A&ntilde;o: <br>
        <select name=nuevo_ano>';

//este bucle se podría hacer dependiendo del número de año que se quiera mostrar
//yo voy a mostar 10 años atrás y 10 adelante de la fecha mostrada en el calendario
for ($anoactual=$ano-10; $anoactual<=$ano+10; $anoactual++){
    echo '<option value="' . $anoactual . '" ';
    if ($ano==$anoactual) {
        echo "selected";
    }
    echo '>' . $anoactual . '</option>';
}
echo '
    </select>
        </td>';
echo '
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="Submit" value="[ IR A ESE MES ]"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>

    <br>

    </form>';
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Función que escribe en la página un fomrulario preparado para introducir una fecha y enlazado con el calendario para seleccionarla comodamente
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function escribe_formulario_fecha_vacio($nombrecampo,$nombreformulario){
    //Esa variable $raiz sirve para cuando se llama al calendario desde otra ruta, para poder acceder a él
    global $raiz; //empieza en . termina en /
    echo '
    <INPUT name="'.$nombrecampo.'" size="10" class="inputfecha" onclick="muestraCalendario(\''. $raiz.'\',\''. $nombreformulario .'\',\''.$nombrecampo.'\')" onfocus="blur()">
    </div>
    ';  
}
?>
```

I appreciate any help and effort

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten messages yet about SQL injection attacks. You should never use data straight from your POST array like that. Look at PDO or using mysqli statements.

Comment: There's a lot of code to go through there, but quite a bit of it looks like it duplicates what php's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class does, along with DateInterval. If you work with DateTime objects and only convert to strings when you absolutely have to, (and consider using UNIX timestamps in your queries as well), then chances are your problem will go away. It's a big refactor, but boy will you be happier once it's over.